# Any downsides to using a pre-packaged cloud Bitnami stack over individual modules?

Tags: amazon-web-services, wordpress, lamp, google-cloud-platform, bitnami

Specifically Bitnami's WordPress stack for GCP or AWS - are there any drawbacks to using their quick pre-packaged bundle instead of manually installing and configuring a LAMP stack and WordPress other than the slightly different install path?

Is there any reason to consider using non-Bitnami individual modules for future configuration/tweaking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up everything from scratch on AWS and [wrote a tutorial](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-pt1-introduction-configuration-downloads/) on it, I wouldn't do it again. It took me two months, even though I'm very technical I'd never done much Unix admin and no Nginx before.

If I did it again I'd use [EasyEngine](https://easyengine.io/). You set up your server, run this, and it sets Wordpress and all required software (Nginx, caching, etc) up. I'd do it this way as it's a balance of control and automation.

Bitnami is likely fine. You can change just about anything on the install once it's done anyway.

Another important note is DO NOT use Amazon Linux. It works ok, but there's just not near the support or resources available for it. There's virtually nothing on Amazon Linux online, and you never know if it's Centos 5, 6, or 7 you need help with. I would use Ubuntu 16.04, which while new is built on a rich history and large community.

Answer (score 1):

Bitnami Developer here.

The main difference between using the Bitnami WordPress Stack or using the Bitnami LAMP Stack and install the WordPress module is that the WP stack do not include some development components. In other words, the LAMP stack includes some component such as the frameworks (Laravel, Symphony, Codeigniter, etc.), Memcached or Varnish which can be useful for other php applications but, since we do not use them on the WordPress configuration, they are skipped on the WordPress Stack.

My suggestion is to use the WordPress Stack instead of the LAMP unless you want to use the server for other projects apart from hosting your WordPress blog.